# Error connecting database to web application

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm pretty new at database driven web applications. When I try and run my web application I am getting following error.

> "Error    1   'FinalProject.projectDBEntities1' does not contain a
>   definition for 'messages' and no extension method 'messages' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'FinalProject.projectDBEntities1' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I thought I did everything right, but apparently not. Please let me know what I did wrong? Here's my code:
Also here's a screenshot of my database table as well. 
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace FinalProject 
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalScore = 0;
        String name = nameTextBox.Text;

        difficultyLabel.Visible = true;
        difficultyLabel.Text = "Difficulty Level: " + difficultyList.SelectedValue;
        learnLabel.Visible = false;
        enterNameLabel.Visible = false;
        nameTextBox.Visible = false;
        difficultyList.Visible = false;
        getStartedButton.Visible = false;
        chooseDifficultyLabel.Visible = false;
        //chosenLabel.Visible = true;
        changeDifficultyButton.Visible = true;
        scoreLabel.Visible = true;
        myScoresButton.Visible = true;
        startOverButton.Visible = true;
        welcomeUsernameLabel.Visible = true;
        welcomeUsernameLabel.Text = "Welcome " + nameTextBox.Text;
        scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " + totalScore;
    }

    protected void changeDifficultyButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        difficultyLabel.Visible = false;
        chooseDifficultyLabel.Visible = true;
        difficultyList.Visible = true;
        changeDifficultyButton.Visible = false;
        myScoresButton.Visible = false;
        startOverButton.Visible = false;
        getStartedButton.Visible = true;
        scoreLabel.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void myScoresButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (projectDBEntities1 dbcontext = new projectDBEntities1())
        {
            Message message = new Message();

            message.userName = nameTextBox.Text;
            message.highScoreEasy = "High Score on Easy: " + easyScoreLabel.Text;
            message.highScoreMedium = "High Score on Medium: " + mediumScoreLabel.Text;
            message.highScoreHard = "High Score on Hard: " + hardScoreLabel.Text; 
          dbcontext.messages.Add(message);
            dbcontext.SaveChanges();


   }

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }






}
}
```

Comment: Error message is clear IMO. There is no `messages` belongs on `Message` class. What is `Message` by the way? Is it a custom class that you defined?

Comment: I thought it was a predefined class. messages is the table name you see in the screenshot in the server explorer and message is what I created with what I thought was a predefined class with this line of code.  Message message = new Message(); If that's not the case, what do you recommend I do?

Comment: Didn't took a very close look at your question, but try the following: Update the edmx, make sure the EDMX is connected to the right database. By the way, can you post the "Message" class??

Comment: It looks like there is a mismatch in your DbSet name which you can locate in our DbContext class. Look for it and make sure you have "messages" in there somewhere and that it is mapped to a data model named "Message".